# How does a request reach the correct server?

Tags: networking

When I enter 66.211.160.88 into the web browser, how does my computer manage to find the correct server behind that IP? The request is sent to the ISP, but now what? How does it know exactly which way to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a video that illustrate your question can be viewed at
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XP61HtbGPbA,

for a bit more complete simple explanaition you can refer to:
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet-infrastructure.htm
for a simple and yet good overview of the way things go.